# How I can find the different routes between two places in Google map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to show different routes between two places in Google map.

For ex: 
Source: Bangalore & 
Destination: Chennai.

Route 1: Bangalore -> Vellore -> Krishnagiri -> Chennai
Route 2: Bangalore -> Dasarahalli -> Palamaner -> Chennai
Route 3: --------

As like three routes I need to show in my project, any idea.?

Answer (score 4):

You must

1. set the `provideRouteAlternatives`-property of the `DirectionsRequest` to `true`(the response then may, when available, return multiple routes)
2. to be able to draw multiple routes via the `DirectionsRenderer` you must use multiple `DirectionsRenderer`-instances(1 for each route). Iterate over the `routes`, create a new `DirectionsRenderer`-instance, call the `setDirections`-method of the `DirectionsRenderer` and then set the `routeIndex`-property of the DirectionsRenderer to the  index of the current route in the `routes`-array.  (of course you should clear previously drawn routes before you render the new routes when you do it repeatedly)